# Capitalise few characters in a word

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed

This might be a crazy scenario but just wanted to know is there any way we can capitalise few of the character in a word without a delimiter (to identify the character to capitalise )

For eg:-
I/P
candidatefirstname
candidatecity

O/P
CandidateFirstName
CandidateCity

Comment: Do you want `inwood` capitalized as `InWood` based on the two words it contains or capitalized as `Inwood` because `Inwood` is the name of a village in New York, USA?

Comment: Your question requires artificial intelligence.

Comment: Yes @John1024 I want something like “InWood” and not like first character of a word

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov or at least a dictionary

Comment: Can't work, the problem here is that have you have words (English is not my native language so I can't really think of one) with the property that *foo* is a valid word, *bar* is valid, but so is *foobar*. So both *Foobar* as *FooBar* would be valid. How can the code know what you want ?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashnikov: sorry , I know it's off topic, but I can't help myself. Rather than AI (even a very limited AI), the task would require some NLP, a very small subset of the broaad swath of technologies used in AI.

Comment: Since "can", "did" and "ate" are valid words in English, CanDidAteFirstName is also possible. What is your proposed rule? Should the division use the longest possible words? The problem is that looking for the longest words may leave less coverage than using shorter words. E.g. it may be the case that for some input, we find two nice, long words, but which leaves a three character gap that isn't a word. Yet, the same input can be covered by five shorter words without any non-word junk.

Comment: @Kaz I guess it is also possible to split words based on n-gram frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the program below in [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp for solving this problem. This relies on a `/usr/share/dict/words` dictionary file being available; plus it adds some words of its own that are common abbreviations found in identifiers in computer programs. I found some sources of these and added a few myself.

The program builds a trie out of the dictionary using TXR Lisp's built-in trie facility. The trie structure is poorly optimized for large dictionaries and rather memory hungry, and the code is a bit clumsy; it could benefit from streamlining.

At the highest level, the function `camelize` returns a list of camel case versions of a word that it believes are good (often just one), trying to implement the requirement of this question.

I left it as that; just a function we can explore using the REPL; no wrapped-up utility:

```
$ txr -i camel.tl
Do not operate heavy equipment or motor vehicles while using TXR.
1> (camelize "shellexecuteex")
("ShellExecuteEx")
2> (camelize "getenvptr")
("GetEnvPtr")
3> (camelize "hownowbrowncow")
("HowNowBrownCow")
4> (camelize "arcanthill")
("ArcAnthill")
5> (camelize "calcmd5digest")
("CalcMd5Digest")
6> (camelize "themother")
("TheMother" "ThemOther")
```

At the heart of how it works is the function `break-word` which returns a list of all the possible divisions of a word into pieces.

The algorithm is recursive and works roughly like this:

1. Try to find all prefixes of the given word which are found in the dictionary. For instance, `albumin` gives us the prefixes `a`, `alb`, `album` and `albumin`.
2. If one or more prefixes are found, recurse: for each prefix, find the possible ways of breaking the suffix into words, and to each possibility, prepend the prefix.
3. If no prefixes are found, the word starts with junk characters that are not in the dictionary. In this case, scan successive positions of the word to see if a dictionary word occurs. For instance if we have `34albumin`, the `3` and `4` will be skipped, and then `a` is found.  When the junk is delimited, treat it as a word: recurse on the rest of the word and combine, similarly to step 2.

The `camelize` function takes the output of `break-word` and selects a set of candidate breakdowns as follows.

1. Each division into words is assigned a sort key which consists of a pair of numbers: the *junk quantity* of that word division, and the *length*.  The junk quantity is the number of characters that didn't come from the dictionary. The length is the number of elements in that word division.
2. We sort the list of breakdowns according to the key determined in 1. Word breakdowns that contain more junk characters are considered strictly worse. When two word breakdowns contain the same number of junk characters, the one with more pieces in it is considered worse.   For instance in the case of `themother`, there are two breakdowns `the` `mother` and `them` `other`.  These both have zero junk characters: their junk quantity is zero. And they are both two elements long, so are equivalent. The algorithm chooses both of them.
3. After sorting in step 2, we group the sort by equivalent keys, and choose the best group.  Then we produce CamelCase from that group.

Junk is identified in the word breakdowns by a list annotation: it looks like `(:junk "grf")`. For instance `cat3dog` will produce a breakdown which looks like `("cat" (:junk "3") "dog")`.   The code in the `junk-quantity` and `camelize` functions uses a bit of structural pattern matching to deal with this.

Long inputs take some time: e.g. this one takes a few seconds. This could be sped up by compiling the code. The `break-word` function could benefit from memoization also, because the recursive search will calculate many identical suffix breakdowns due to trying prefix combinations that add up to the same thing.

```
1> (camelize "nowisthetimeforallgoodmentocometotheaidoftheircountry")
("NoWistHeTimeForAllGoodMenToComeToTheAidOfTheirCountry" 
 "NoWistHeTimeForAllGoodMenToComeToTheAidOftHeirCountry"
 "NoWistHeTimeForAllGoodMenToComeTotHeAidOfTheirCountry"
 "NoWistHeTimeForAllGoodMenToComeTotHeAidOftHeirCountry"
 "NoWistHeTimeForaLlGoodMenToComeToTheAidOfTheirCountry"
 "NoWistHeTimeForaLlGoodMenToComeToTheAidOftHeirCountry"
 "NoWistHeTimeForaLlGoodMenToComeTotHeAidOfTheirCountry"
 "NoWistHeTimeForaLlGoodMenToComeTotHeAidOftHeirCountry"
 "NowIsTheTimeForAllGoodMenToComeToTheAidOfTheirCountry"
 "NowIsTheTimeForAllGoodMenToComeToTheAidOftHeirCountry"
 "NowIsTheTimeForAllGoodMenToComeTotHeAidOfTheirCountry"
 "NowIsTheTimeForAllGoodMenToComeTotHeAidOftHeirCountry"
 "NowIsTheTimeForaLlGoodMenToComeToTheAidOfTheirCountry"
 "NowIsTheTimeForaLlGoodMenToComeToTheAidOftHeirCountry"
 "NowIsTheTimeForaLlGoodMenToComeTotHeAidOfTheirCountry"
 "NowIsTheTimeForaLlGoodMenToComeTotHeAidOftHeirCountry")
```

(Why is this finding `ForaLlGood`? Because `ll` is listed as a word, due to being used as an abbreviation in computing identifiers.)

Just the code now:

```
(defvarl %dict% "/usr/share/dict/words")

(defun trie-dict (dict)
  (let ((trie (make-trie)))
    (each ((word dict))
      (if (> (len word) 2)
        (trie-add trie word t)))
    (each ((word '#"a I ad am an as at ax be by do ex go he hi \
                    id if in is it lo me mi my no of oh on or \
                    ow ox pa pi re so to un up us we abs act \
                    addr alloc alt arg attr app arr auth avg \
                    bat bg bin bool brk btn buf char calc cb \
                    cert cfg ch chr circ clr cmd cmp cnt \
                    concat conf config conn cont conv col coll \
                    com cord coord cos csum ctrl ctx cur cpy \
                    db dbg dec def def del dest dev dev diff \
                    dir dis disp doc drv dsc dt en enc env eq err \
                    expr exch exchg fig fmt fp func ge gen gt hex \
                    hdr hor hw id idx iface img inc info init int \
                    lang lat lib le len ll lon math max mem mcu \
                    mid min misc mng mod msg ne net num obj ord \
                    op os param pic pos posix pred pref prev proc \
                    prof ptr pwr px qry rand rect recv rem res \
                    ret rev req rng rx sem sel seq stat std str \
                    sin sqrt src swp sync temp temp tgl tmp tmr \
                    tran trans ts tx txt unix usr val var vert win \
                    xform xmit xref xtract"))
      (trie-add trie word t))
    trie))

(defvarl %trie% (trie-dict (file-get-lines %dict%)))

(defun break-word (trie word)
  (iflet ((lw (len word))
          ((plusp lw)))
    (build
      (let ((i 0)
            (cursor (trie-lookup-begin trie)))
        (whilet ((next (if (< i lw)
                         (trie-lookup-feed-char cursor [word i]))))
          (inc i)
          (set cursor next)
          (if (trie-value-at next)
            (let ((first-word [word 0..i])
                  (rest-words (break-word trie [word i..:])))
              (if rest-words
                (each ((rest-wordlist rest-words))
                  (add ^(,first-word ,*rest-wordlist)))
                (add ^(,first-word))))))
        (unless (get)
          (for ((j 1)) ((and (< j lw) (not (get)))) ((inc j))
            (let ((i j)
                  (cursor (trie-lookup-begin trie)))
              (whilet ((next (if (and (< i lw) (not (get)))
                               (trie-lookup-feed-char cursor [word i]))))
                (inc i)
                (set cursor next)
                (if (trie-value-at next)
                  (let ((junk-word [word 0..j])
                        (rest-words (break-word trie [word j..:])))
                    (each ((rest-wordlist rest-words))
                      (add ^((:junk ,junk-word) ,*rest-wordlist)))))))))
        (unless (get)
          (add ^((:junk ,word))))))))

(defun junk-quantity (broken-word)
  (let ((char-count 0))
    (each ((word broken-word))
      (if-match (:junk @str) word
        (inc char-count (len str))))
    char-count))

(defun camelize (word)
  (if (empty word)
    word
    (flow (break-word %trie% word)
      (mapcar [juxt [juxt junk-quantity len] use])
      (sort @1 : first)
      (partition-by first)
      first
      (mapcar second)
      (mapcar
        (opip (mapcar (do match @(or `@{x 1}@y`
                                     (:junk `@{x 1}@y`))
                                @1
                         `@(upcase-str x)@y`))
              cat-str)))))
```